# Hibernate OGM with MongoDB using NamedQueries

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, named-query, hibernate-ogm

question is simple does Hibernate OGM actually supports NamedQueries at current time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , the latest version of Hibernate OGM 4.0.0 does support Named Queries. Check this out : [Hibernate OGM FAQ](http://hibernate.org/ogm/faq/)

Comment: Wonderful, looks like simple once are working but not the once with join :-(

Comment: MongoDB itself does not support joins, so there is no way to translate joins from JP-QL queries. We might translate it into a batch select of the "joined" entity, but that's just a rough idea at this point.